# ¿Explicación de funciones flecha en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Se que es una pregunta sencilla pero no acabo de entederla. He buscado tutoriales en YouTube y he buscado por la red, y no encuentro una aclaración.

```
    const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
setValues({ ...values, error: false, [name]: event.target.value });}
```

Qué está ocurriendo dentro? Parecerá raro pero no encuentro una explicación clara. He probado buscando en funciones flecha de Mozilla Developer, en YouTube, en funciones Lambda... Y no me aclaro.

EDIT: Vale, he buscado y algo más me he aclarado, pero sigo sin entender la parte del `=> (event)`. Tenía entendido que después de la función de flecha viene la sentencia, o la expresión, no que se podía meter otra función de flecha.

Comment: En JS las funciones son *ciudadanos de primera clase*. Por lo tanto puedes asignar funciones a variables y pasar funciones como argumento. Incluso en tu código puedes prescindir de los paréntesis si el argumento es único: `const handleChange = name => event => { ... }`. A ver que alguien con un poco más de dedicación te dará una respuesta indicando esta y otro tipo de características del lenguaje. Esto es parte del llamado *paradigma* de la [programación funcional](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programación_funcional) . Saludos

Comment: Entre tu explicación y la que me dan abajo ya me ha quedado mucho más claro. Como pensaba, era mucho más sencillo de lo que yo veía. Gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las *arrow functions* es otra forma sintáctica de declarar funciones en *JavaScript* a partir del ES2015.

La sintaxis es

```
const fn = () => {
  // body
}

fn();
```

---

#### Características

1. **Son expresiones**
   Siempre son expresiones, a diferencia de `function` (que puede ser expresión o declaración).
   Esto implica que siempre deberemos asignar la expresión a una variable (o una constante).
2. **No se aplica el *hoisting***
   El *hoisting* es una técnica del *parser* de *JavaScript* que pone automáticamente todas las variables declaradas con `var` arriba del todo de una función y, también se aplica a las declaraciones de las funciones.

```
// Todo bien
declaration();

function declaration() {
  console.log(`Hurray`);
}

// ReferenceError: Cannot access 'expression' before initialization
expression();

const expression = () => {
  console.log(`Nope`);
}
```

3. **No tienen un contexto de `this` propio**
   Las funciones declaradas con `function` tienen una palabra reservada `this` que hace referencia a su contexto de función.
   De este modo es como antes del ES2015 se escribían las clases (o algo que pretendía emularlo).
   En el caso de las *arrow function*, el `this` viene determinado a la función padre o a la `class` que las contenga.

```
function Counter() {
  // Tenemos que guardar la referencia
  // a la instancia de Counter
  self = this;
  // Declaramos una propiedad de la instancia
  // en el contexto de Counter
  this.index = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    // this.counter es undefined
    // porque this forma parte de otro contexto

    console.log(self.index++);
  }, 1000);
}

Counter();

///////////////////

function Counter() {
  this.index = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    // this hace referencia al contexto
    // de Counter. No se ha creado
    // un nuevo contexto en este scope
    console.log(this.index++);
  }, 1000);
}

Counter();
```

---

#### Sintaxis

1. **Un solo parámetro no necesita paréntesis**
   (A excepción de los *rest parameters* o una deconstrucción de un objeto)

```
// No necesita paréntesis
const monadic = arg => {
  console.log(arg);
}

// Necesita paréntesis
const diadic = (arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

// Necesita paréntesis
const multiple = (...args) => {
  console.log(...args);
}

// Necesita paréntesis
const property = ({ index }) => {
  console.log(index);
}

monadic(`One`);
diadic(`One`, `Two`);
multiple(`One`, `Two`, `... and so on`);
property({
  first: `One`,
  index: `Two`
});
```

2. **`return` implícito**
   Una *arrow function* sin *curly brakets* (llaves) tiene un `return` implícito que devolverá el resultado de la expresión.
   Sólo es válido en caso de una sola expresión; si hay dos o más, se necesitan llaves siempre.

```
const sum = (x, y) => x + y;

const res = sum(10, 13);
console.log(res); // 23

// Tiene dos líneas, pero sólo
// una expresión (statement)
const delay = millis =>
  new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, millis));
```

> *`return` implícito de un `object`*
> Por sintaxis, para poder usar el `return` implícito en caso de retornar un objeto, los *curly brackets* del objeto envuelven en paréntesis para que no haya ambigüedad entre los *curly brackets* del cuerpo de la función y la declaración del objeto.

```
const merge = (obj1, obj2) => ({ ...obj1, ...obj2 }); // Ok
const merge = (obj1, obj2) => { ...obj1, ...obj2 }; // syntax error
```

---

#### Otras implicaciones

1. **No pueden ser invocadas con el operador `new`**
2. **No tienen un `prototype` definido** (causa del punto 1)
3. **No pueden ser funciones generadoras** (causa de la sintaxis)
4. **Sí pueden ser funciones asíncronas** (`const fn = async () => { ... }`)

---

#### Tu ejemplo

Reescribimos la función con sintaxis pre-ES2015

```
function handleChange(name) {
  return function(event) {
    var param = {
      ...values, // El spread no es pre-ES2015, pero lo dejamos así por simplicidad
      error: false,
      [name]: event.target.value
    };

    setValues(param);
  }
}
```

Es una función que devuelve otra función. Tan simple.
Se aplican dos características de la sintaxis de las *arrow functions*: obviar paréntesis y el `return` implícito.

Si queda cualquier otra duda, coméntame.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Ah! Vale, ahora sí está todo aclarado. En el código que he puesto, declaro una constante, meto dentro de esta una función anónima con el argumento (name), y el paso siguiente es que va a retornar una función anónima con el argumento (event), y a partir de ahí ya opera con la lógica que se le indique. Creo que es así, si no me he confundido. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es exactamente eso, sí. Justo como se ve en la "traducción" que hice es pre-ES2015

Comment: Excelente respuesta!, brillante! +1.