# Promises anidadas

Tags: javascript, web, aplicación-web, promesas

Tengo alguna promises, por ejemplo:

```
promise1 = function() { return new Promise(a,b){} ....}

promise2 = function() { return new Promise(a,b){} ....}

promise3 = function() { return new Promise(a,b){} ....}

promise4 = function() { return new Promise(a,b){} ....}
```

Es posible crear otras Promises anidando estas promises (1,2,3,4), por ejemplo:

```
 promiseX = function() {

     return new Promise(function() {

         promise1().then(promise2)...          

     })

 }

 promiseY = function() {

     return new Promise(function() {

         promise3().then(promise4).....        

     })

 }
```

Para luego utilizar las dos ultimas creadas:

```
promiseX().then(promiseY).then(function().....)
```

¿Es correcto hacer esto? ¿Cual seria la manera correcta de hacerlo en todo caso?

Comment: Lo normal seria preguntarse si es buena idea anidar tantas promises y cual es el proposito de anidar tantas promises, normalmente yo nunca anido tantas promises, pero cuando se trata de querer ejecutar varias promises al tiempo en vez de anidarlas se algo que podria mejorar muchisimo ese inconveniente.

Comment: La verdad es que no tiene mucho sentido. Dentro de una `Promise` puedes esperar lo que necesites para resolverla. Es decir, si dentro de una `Promise` tienes que estar esperando a otra, en vez de resolver la primera con la segunda (`Promise<Promise<T>>`), simplemente no resuelves la primera hasta que la segunda no se resuelva.

Comment: Dejo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/nL42ozes/) un pequeño ejemplo que reproduce lo que acabo de comentar.

Comment: Otra cosa muy diferente es el hecho de anidar `Promise` que tú no controlas por el hecho de encontrarse en otras capas de abstracción o requerir resultados unas de otras y necesitas un orquestador. En cualquier caso, nunca se ve el patrón de `Promise<Promise<T>>` sinó que se van encadenando. La misma resolución de una `Promise` (des de la capa superior) devolverá otra `Promise`. Dejo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/bg5wu3sj/) otro ejemplo con esta distinción. No es **`Promise` *nesting***, sinó **`Promise` *chaining***.

Answer (score 1):

Te diría que usaras `Promise.all` para solucionar tu problema, pero creo que no he entendido bien la pregunta o para lo que quieres usar tu anidación, sin embargo de todas maneras por si de algo sirve y entendí bien la pregunta puedes usar `Promise.all` para generar una simulacion de jerarquia de promises.

**Eso si, el inconveniente de usar Promise.all, es que segun su definicion:**

> `Promise.all` devolvera una `Promise` que se resuelve al momento que
>   todas las promises a iterar sean resueltas o se rechaza cuando al
>   menos una de ellas es rechazada.

Debes tener en cuenta esto a la hora de usar `Promise.all`.

Entonces según lo que requieres veo que tu estas separando de **2** en **2** a las **promises** para ser ejecutadas, por lo que mi sugerencia es realizar algo como lo siguiente:

```js
const promise1 = function() { return new Promise((a,b) => a("a"))}
const promise2 = function() { return new Promise((a,b) => a("b"))}
const promise3 = function() { return new Promise((a,b) => a("c"))}
const promise4 = function() { return new Promise((a,b) => a("d"))}

//PromiseX
Promise.all([promise1(), promise2()]).then(promiseX =>{

  console.log(promiseX);
  
  //PromiseY
  Promise.all([promise3(), promise4()]).then(promiseY =>{
    console.log(promiseY);
  });

});
```

No se si es lo que deseabas en un inicio, `Promise.all` es una forma de iterar sobre **promises** de tal forma que cuando se resuelva la promise devuelta por `Promise.all` obtengamos ya sea un array de valores (valores devueltos en la `Promise`) o un error correspondiente.

Las cosas que cambie en tu codigo son las siguientes:

- Tus promises estaban mal declaradas, tuve que cambiarlas a fin de poder usarlas.
- Le añadí una `arrow function` a cada `promise` para poder que se ejecutase el cuerpo de la `arrow function`, en tu caso no tenias cuerpo (tu sintaxis era erronea), vale la pena decir que tambien puedes usar `function` en vez de `arrow functions`.
- las constantes PromiseX y PromiseY ya no existen porque considere de que enrealidad no eran necesarias, en su lugar fueron reemplazadas por `Promise.all`.

**Nota:** Una `arrow function` es una función de cuerpo corta sin contexto que te permite acortar mucho tu código y a la vez mejorar la legibilidad, fueron introducidas en `ES6`, si quieres saber mas información sobre las `arrow functions` en la descripción podrás ver el enlace de `VRoxa` acerca de las `arrow functions` que explica mas en profundidad.

Comment: @VRoxa he visto hace poco una respuesta en la que describiste muy bien las arrow functions, podrias anexarla por aqui porfavor?, es un buen recurso a tener en cuenta.

Comment: [Toda tuya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363155/explicaci%c3%b3n-de-funciones-flecha-en-javascript/363175#363175), @Riven

Comment: Gracias VRoxa ;3