# Función map() no me da los resultados que espero, en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

Mi código debe cumplir las siguientes condiciones:

La función llamada 'pluck' recibe como argumento un array de objetos llamado 'array' y el nombre de una propiedad. La función debe devolver un nuevo arreglo con solo los valores dentro de la propiedad recibida

Ej:

```
var productos = [{ name: 'TV LCD', price: 100}, { name: 'Computadora', price: 500 }]
```

`productos.pluck(productos, 'name')` debería devolver `['TV LCD', 'Computadora']`

No logro encontrar el error. Como seria el código? Por que mi código da el siguiente error:

```
"Expected value to equal:
["TV LCD", "Computadora"]

Received: undefined"
```

Mi código es el de a continuación:

```
function pluck(array, propiedad) {  
    let nuevoArray = array.map(function(propiedad){
    return propiedad;
    });
}
```

No logro encontrar el error que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿En qué parte necesitas ayuda?, ¿cuáles son las dudas?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: En la parte del código. Porque me tira ese error. Me gustaría saber que estoy poniendo mal

Comment: Una pregunta difícil de entender ya que está mal planteada. :/

Answer (score 2):

**Lo que está mal en tu código:**

1. El argumento que le pasas a `map()` es una función que devuelve el mismo argumento anónimo que le pasaste, esto no tiene sentido y tampoco utilidad.

**ES5:**

```
function pluck(array, propiedad) {
    let nuevoArray = array.map(function(a){
        return a[propiedad]
    });
    return nuevoArray;
}
```

**ES6:**

Con uso del "arrow function":

```
function pluck(array, propiedad) {
    let nuevoArray = array.map((a) => a[propiedad]);
    return nuevoArray;
}
```

**Nota:** Cualquiera de las dos formas son válidas

**Un pequeño ejemplo:**

El código con el array, función y uso quedaría así:

```
//El array conteniendo objetos con el que vamos a trabajar
var productos = [{ name: 'TV LCD', price: 100}, { name: 'Computadora', price: 500 }]

//La función que nos va a hacer el trabajo
function pluck(array, propiedad) {
    let nuevoArray = array.map((a) => a[propiedad]);
    return nuevoArray;
}

//La invocación de la función 'console.log()', para ver resultados
console.log(pluck(productos,'name'))
```

La salida en nodejs:

```
[ 'TV LCD', 'Computadora' ]
```

La salida en el navegador Chrome:

```
["TV LCD", "Computadora"]
0: "TV LCD"
1: "Computadora"
```

Comment: Gracias por la contribuciòn pero preferentemente debemos responder a preguntas que sean realizadas en base a [ask], de otra forma estamos contribuyendo a agregar informaciòn que no es de calidad a el sitio, saludos.

Comment: Ojo las functions no son innecesarias, de hecho creer que las arrow functions las sustituyen es un error grande desde el momento que incluso sus contextos respecto a this varían

Comment: Por cierto son arrow functions o funciones flecha, las array functions quien sabe que serán

Comment: @BetaM ya corregí array por arrow, es que me equivoqué son muy paecidas ambas palabras

Comment: @BetaM yo tenía entendido que las arrow functions reemplazaban las funciones anónimas. Gracias por corregirme, me explicas?

Comment: El contenido es muy amplio, pero te recomiendo investigues al respecto, un buen punto de partida será investigar por qué vue en determinadas partes de su instancia marca como error usar una arrow function y no una regular

Comment: @gabrielcoronel para cubrir aquello que intenta explicar `BetaM` sobre lo de los contextos desiguales y el porque `NO` se considera a las `arrow functions` como el reemplazo de las `funciones` normales te dejo una respuesta de mi amigo `VRoxa` el cual explica muy bien esto, cubre practicamente todo acerca de las `arrow functions`, pero en definitiva las `arrow function` no hacen que las `function` normales esten obsoletas o sean su reemplazo, puesto que debido a sus diferentes contextos a vecez requeriras `arrow functions`, otras vecez `funciones` normales,  aqui esta el link:

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363155/explicaci%c3%b3n-de-funciones-flecha-en-javascript/363175#363175

Comment: Ok, gracias a los dos.